# Ambiguous column error using orange3 - POSTGRES

Tags: postgresql, orange

When executing the query inside [Orange 3](https://orange.biolab.si/), I got an ambiguous column error

**QUERY**

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(memoria_em_uso, 'G','') AS FLOAT),
       CAST(REPLACE(memoria_total, 'G','') as FLOAT), 
       CAST(REPLACE(memoria_livre, 'M','') as FLOAT) 
FROM tbl_memoria_hosts
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Error encountered in widget SQL Table:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/luis/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Orange/data/sql/backend/postgres.py", line 81, in execute_sql_query
    cur.execute(query, params)
psycopg2.errors.AmbiguousColumn: column reference "replace" is ambiguous
LINHA 1: SELECT (("replace")::double precision) AS "replace", (("repl...
```

**Note:**

All columns in the table are VARCHAR, where the information is written as follows `7.7G`

Comment: This Orange thing seems to rewrite the query. Try to explicitly provide column aliases: e.g. `CAST(REPLACE(memoria_em_uso, 'G','') AS FLOAT) as memoria_em_us`

Comment: returned: relation "CAST(REPLACE(memoria_em_uso, 'G','') AS FLOAT) as memoria_em_us..." does not exist
LINHA 1: SELECT * FROM "CAST(REPLACE(memoria_em_uso, 'G','') AS FLOAT...

Comment: No, don't put it into the FROM clause: `SELECT CAST(REPLACE(memoria_em_uso, 'G','') AS FLOAT) as memoria_em_uso,
       CAST(REPLACE(memoria_total, 'G','') as FLOAT) as memoria_total, ... FROM tbl_memoria_hosts`